# BigQuery:Invalid date Error

Tags: google-bigquery

When I try to format date in bigquery standard SQL query

```
FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m-%d", cast(costTable.date as DATE))
```

It throws error saying

> Query Failed 
>   Error: Invalid date: '20180403'

Can anyone guide me how to parse the `date` in `yyyy-mm-dd` in bigquery

Answer (score 4):

For BigQuery Standard SQL

```
PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', '20180403')

PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', costTable.date)
```